# Can I customize Emacs via the command line, during startup?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to set a customizable variable when I start Emacs? E.g. I have a project name variable, which I usually set interactively using `M-x customize-variable`, but I'd like to set it already when starting Emacs. I.e. so I can choose a project from the command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run

```
emacs --eval '(setq variable-name value)'
```

to do this. Or you could edit your settings file in such a way that it reads the customization from some environment variable, and set that on the command line.

Comment: +1 for the environment variable! Can you give a complete example please?

Comment: @Dror You can use the `getenv` function to read an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question as asked, but "automatically set a project name variable" sounds quite a lot like a job for [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).